# Making sure that JavaScript function loads before the iFrame

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JavaScript function with an event listener that is waiting for an event triggered by an iFrame.
In other words, when the iFrame loads it triggers an event and my JS function runs some DOM actions as soon as it gets that event.

The problem I'm facing is that there is a race between my function and the loading of the iFrame. It means that sometimes the iFrame is loading and triggering its event before my JS function is even ready. And so, when the JS function loads to listen for the iFrame event the event has already triggered.

To fix this I need to make sure that my JS function is always loading before the iFrame.

**I can think of two solutions here:**

1. Using a setTimeOut for loading the iFrame to defer its loading.
2. Loading the iframe inside window.addEventListener('load', () => {} to make sure that it's loading after everything else including my JS function is loaded.

I went with the second solution but then I got this comment:

> I think that your solution is too aggressive. The **iFrame can be
> loaded as soon as the event listener is registered**; it doesn’t need
> to defer until the “load” event, which fires once all page resources
> have been loaded.

I'm not sure what the above comment means exactly. How do I know when the event listener is registered?
Does anyone know a better solution to make sure that my JS function loads always before the iFrame.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the person who made the comment to explain in more detail?

Comment: Also, it difficult to comment without seeing the relevant code!

Comment: It's difficult to give you any concrete help with the information you've provided. One possible solution could be to have some code that runs before everything else and keeps track of the two events (your function being ready and the iframe event) and invokes your functionality only when both events have happened, whichever order that occurred.